# AngularJS: Mock Controller Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to mock a service for a controller but struggling to get it to work.

Using semi-psudeo code I have a service:

```
.factory('SomeService', ['$http'function($http) {

    var someService = {};

    someService.getData=function(val1, val2){
        ...
        return someData;
    }

    return someService;
}
```

And a controller like so:

```
 .controller('someController', ['SomeService', function(SomeService){
    var self = this;
    var data = [];

    self.getSomeData = = function(){
         var response = SomeService.getSomething.then(function(response){
              self.data = response;
         });
    };
 }]);
```

I am trying to write a test that uses a $provide to mock the service. Something like this:

```
var mockService

beforeEach(module(function($provide){
    mockService.getSomething = function(){ 

            return   [ ....];
    };

    $provide.value('SomeService', mockService);

}));
```

After injecting this mock and running the test I get:

Typeerror: cannot set property getSomething of undefined

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code (or right)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `mockService` an object:

```
describe('Some Service', function(){
    var mockService;

    beforeEach(module(function($provide){
        mockService = {
            getSomething: function () {
                return {
                    then: function (success, error) {
                        success(true);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        $provide.value('SomeService', mockService);
    }));
});
```

I would recommend looking through [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller), as they can be very helpful.

Comment: In the beforeEach function?

Comment: yes. I have updated my answer to provide a little more clarity.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this is not working. If I use your exact code above I get: cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

Comment: That is a different problem. Now you need to learn how to mock a promise response.